Connections with Microsoft SQL Server are 5 times slower on Linux compared to Windows
I am connecting to Microsoft SQL Server from a Linux machine.
I have setup my entire cluster. I thought everything is working fine, then observed that all the API calls are very slow..
SETUP
My cluster with services is running in my office server room, and I have Microsoft SQL Server running on a Windows machine just beside it.
Now my requests to that SQL Server are 5-6x slower than my earlier setup, where requests used to go from services running on IIS on a Windows machine to SQL Server running on Windows.
I ran the profiler and saw that pyodbc.connect is taking 90% of the time.
The query which was taking 500 ms to execute on a Windows machine is now taking 5.2 seconds out of which 4.46 is consumed by pyodbc.connect
Please help.
I found this https://www.unixodbc.org/doc/conn_pool.html
and updated my odbcinst.ini file
[ODBC]
Trace = No
Trace File = /tmp/sql.log
Pooling = Yes

[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.4.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
CPTimeout=60

This is how I use pyodbc to read query
DEFAULT_DRIVER_UNIX = "/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.4.so.1.1"
DEFAULT_DRIVER_ODBC_UNIX = "/usr/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.so"
if platform.system() == "Linux":
    DEFAULT_DRIVER = DEFAULT_DRIVER_UNIX
    DEFAULT_DRIVER_ODBC = DEFAULT_DRIVER_UNIX


def create_db_string(*, server, database, username, password, driver=DEFAULT_DRIVER):
    return (
        f"Driver={driver};"
        f"Server={server};"
        f"Database={database};"
        f"uid={username};"
        f"pwd={password};"
        "Trusted_Connection=no;"
        "integratedSecurity=false;"
"TrustServerCertificate=yes;"
    )
    
   def read_from_db(db_string, query, sorting_index=None, descending=False):
    """given database connection string, and a query returns a sorted list
    of queried items from database"""
    conn = pyodbc.connect(db_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    return_list = list(cursor.fetchall())
    if sorting_index is not None:
        return_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[sorting_index], reverse=descending)
    return return_list


I changed odbcinst.ini file according to the link provided above. Still no change.
Do I have to change code as well? How to solve this issue?

So it's spending 4.46 seconds out of each 5.2 just connecting? That's not normal. I don't suppose you've cranked up Wireshark to see why?

@AlwaysLearning no i have just used python-Werkzeug profiler middleware.

@testing-for-ya i posted this question on pyodbc github issues.
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/discussions/1373#discussioncomment-10213614
One of the contributors mentioned that "Microsoft's ODBC drivers for SQL Server (e.g., msodbcsql18) use connection pooling by default. On Linux, unixODBC does not use connection pooling by default"
and he suggested using this "https://www.unixodbc.org/doc/conn_pool.html"
i updated my odbcinst.ini file accordingly, still no change in performance.
you can see my odbcinst.ini file above.
do we have to implement pooling in codebase aswell?

re: unixODBC connection pooling - I have updated the pyodbc wiki here with the current status.

The issue is with the unixODBC version.
Read these docs, they may help
github issue for reference


What versions of unixODBC and pyodbc are you using?

unixODBC 2.3.9, pyodbc 5.1.0

From the pyodbc wiki:

unixODBC connection pooling
The most recent (as of August 2024) updates to both unixODBC and pyodbc have changed the behaviour of connection pooling under unixODBC. With libmsodbcsql-18.4.so.1.1 (ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server) and pyodbc >= 5.1.0:
unixODBC <= 2.3.9 — Connection pooling does not work at all. pyodbc uses wide (Unicode) connection functions and unixODBC did not start supporting those for connection pooling until 2.3.10.
unixODBC == 2.3.11 — pyodbc defaults to pyodbc.pooling = True but unixODBC ignores that setting, so connection pooling is disabled by default. Adding Pooling = Yes to the [ODBC] section of odbcinst.ini enables connection pooling. Details in the unixODBC documentation here.
unixODBC >= 2.3.12 — unixODBC now respects the pyodbc.pooling setting, so connection pooling is enabled by default. Pooling can be completely disabled by setting pyodbc.pooling = False before the first connection. Pooling can be disabled for a specific driver by adding CPTimeout = -1 (not 0, as currently documented) to the driver's section of odbcinst.ini. Note that pyodbc.pooling = True takes precedence over the Pooling = Yes/No setting in odbcinst.ini.
For more detailed discussion, see Issue 774.

so I updated my version accordingly following this script.
First remove existing packages, to avoid conflicts
sudo cp /etc/odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini.bak
sudo cp /etc/odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini.bak
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq msodbcsql18
sudo apt-get remove --purge unixodbc unixodbc-dev -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get clean

Then run the following script
#!/bin/bash

# Update and upgrade system packages
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

# Install required packages
sudo apt install -y \
    python3 python3-pip \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    wget \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
    dpkg-dev \
    gcc \
    gnupg \
    libbluetooth-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libc6-dev \
    libdb-dev \
    libexpat1-dev \
    libffi-dev \
    libgdbm-dev \
    liblzma-dev \
    libncursesw5-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    make \
    tk-dev \
    uuid-dev \
    wget \
    xz-utils \
    zlib1g-dev \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    g++

# Download, build, and install unixODBC 2.3.12
curl -L http://www.unixodbc.org/unixODBC-2.3.12.tar.gz | tar zx
cd unixODBC-2.3.12
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
rm -rf unixODBC-2.3.12

# Add Microsoft's repository key and list file
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

# Update package lists and install Microsoft ODBC driver and tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18

# Add mssql-tools to PATH
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

# Create symbolic link for the ODBC driver
sudo ln -s /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.4.so.1.1 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.4.so.1.0

# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

updated my odbcinst.ini file and odbc.ini file with the previous configurations mentioned above in the question.
odbcinst -j

will give you the unixODBC version
